# How to calculate the minimum value from set of group of points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-statistics

I have a set of groups of points with similar X and Y values. I want to extract the point which holds the minimum elevation value. Like in this below pic, I want FID 226 which holds the minimum value among all selected points.

[image]

Comment: How do you plan to group your points?

Comment: @Hornbydd Based on location. If you notice X, Y values are same for set of points.

Comment: Concatenate the X and Y into a string field then run your data through the summary statistics tool grouping by the concatenated field and returning the minimum value.

Comment: Yes, But it will return in Nonspatial data, Is there any way I can directly get spatial data?

Comment: Yes then relate that back to your layer. See help file on running relates.

Comment: Dissolve , with z statistics minimum will do the same thing.